# Can someone help me fix my roblox Lua scripting for my leaderboard?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I'm making a script to get +1 coin when left control is pressed. I'm really bad at scripting and i can't find the problem with my code:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local DataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("TimeStats")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    local Leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    Leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    Leaderstats.Parent = Player
    local Coins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Coins.Name = "Coins"
    Coins.Value = 0
    Coins.Parent = Leaderstats

    local Data = DataStore:GetAsync(Player.UserId)
    print(Data)
    if Data then
        Coins.Value = Data
    end


    coroutine.wrap(function()
        print("Coroutine running")
        while true do
            
            if game:GetService("UserInputService"):IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.LeftControl) then
                print("yes")
                
                wait(1)
                Coins.Value = Coins.Value + 1
                print(Coins.Value)
                
            else wait(5)
                print("no")
                
            end
        end
    end)()
end)




game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(Player)
    DataStore:SetAsync(Player.UserId, Player.leaderstats.Coins.Value)
end)
```

I placed that script in ServerScriptService, and when i go on play mode it always print no in continue even when i press left control. I guess that there is a problem with the coroutine but I can't fix it. I would be really gratefull if someone helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use the UserInputService in "Script", UserInputService can only be used in "LocalScript".
Second, your logic in while loop is not good.
Third, You cannot access DataStoreService from LocalScript, You need to Put the Data and leaderboard code in "Script" and listen the input from "LocalScript" and send the event using "RemoteEvent" to the server script to update the coins.
The following code might helps you.

In "LocalScript" place in StarterPlayer:-

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local coinUpdateEvent = ReplicatedStorage.CoinEvent --Reference of your RemoteEvent

game:GetService("UserInputService").InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gameProcessed)
    if input.keyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftControl then
        coinUpdateEvent:FireServer(1) --Fire the event to server script
    end
end)
```

In "Script" place in ServerScriptService:-

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local DataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("TimeStats")
local coinUpdateEvent = ReplicatedStorage.CoinEvent --Reference of your RemoteEvent


coinUpdateEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, value)
    local coins = player.leaderstats.Coins
    coins.Value += value
end)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local Leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    Leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    Leaderstats.Parent = player
    local Coins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Coins.Name = "Coins"
    Coins.Value = 0
    Coins.Parent = Leaderstats

    local Data = DataStore:GetAsync(player.UserId)
    print(Data)
    if Data then
        Coins.Value = Data
    end
end)
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(Player)
    DataStore:SetAsync(Player.UserId, Player.leaderstats.Coins.Value)
end)
```

Comment: I tried the code you sent me and it's not working: there an error for the script located in ServerScriptService, "UnknownGlobal: (21,34) Unknown global 'Player'".

Comment: Just change the "Player.UserId" in the line of "DataStore:GetAsync" method to "player.UserId". I copied this line from your code and forgot to change it with "player.UserId"

Comment: Alright thank you but the leaderboard isn't showing in play mode, i tried to fix it but can't.